# Redis multiple connections opened with TIME_WAIT state

Tags: php, node.js, redis, tcp, netstat

I am using common redis for storing data from almost 60 systems.This common redis is used for communication between all machines. At first everything was seemed to be working fine but as I increased machines from 60 to 80 ,number of connections to redis increased and after that it didn’t start to accept any more connections causing a big problem.

When I started to debug the issue using  'netstat -na | grep 6379' I found out that whenever we connect to redis it opens an TCP/IP connection at particular port and didn’t release that connection and kept that connection in TIME_WAIT state for almost 60 seconds even after calling  $redis->quit() (using predis library of PHP)

Methods I tried to overcome this issue :

1) I tried to decrease timewait seconds in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout but it was not right solution.

2)I shifted from PHP to nodejs and  tried connection pooling in nodejs but no success.Here is sample code

```
app.get('/setinredis',function(req,res){

 var poolRedis = require('pool-redis')({
    'host': 'localhost',
    'password': '',
    'maxConnections': 5
    });

   poolRedis.getClient(function(client, done) {

        client.get('somekey', function(err, value) {
            console.log('value from redis is:', value);
            done();
            res.send({message:"Done"});
        });
    });
```

});

Is there any way to solve this problem efficiently or any alternative to redis with data structure functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have read that you were using quit() on predis library, have you tried `$client->disconnect()`?  i am using phpredis, you can also use close()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're creating a pool every time someone hits your `/setinredis` endpoint. This means if you hit that endpoint 1000 times, you'll create 1000 pools. Move the pool creation outside of the route:

```
var poolRedis = require('pool-redis')({
    'host': 'localhost',
    'password': '',
    'maxConnections': 5
});

app.get('/setinredis',function(req,res){
   poolRedis.getClient(function(client, done) {
        client.get('somekey', function(err, value) {
            console.log('value from redis is:', value);
            done();
            res.send({message:"Done"});
        });
    });
});
```

edit: as a side note, your question is confusing as it refers to PHP yet the code is in Node.js.

Comment: tried that too but still multiple connections with TIME_WAIT state opened.

Comment: With redis pipelining you shouldnt need so many sockets open. Sockets being in TIME_WAIT is not necessarily a problem, only if you exhaust all available ports.

Comment: not sure if pipelining would work here because I need to track response of each system instantly.

Comment: Sorry - what I meant was `node-redis` uses pipelining by default, I read the `pool-redis` documentation briefly and it suggests it's based on `node-redis`. Have you verified you're still having problems since changing this?

Comment: Yes I tried what you said.Also one strange thing I encountered is even if two clients set value in redis then also 10-15 connections are open in TIME_WAIT state when I use nodejs but this was not the problem in PHP.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the standard Node Redis library (https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis)? I notice that library is not very popular and hasnt been updated in 2 years. It is possible there is a bug in that library.

Comment: I am not sure if it has connection pool functionality but will try.

Answer (score 0):

please try this way, it should work fine.

=== controller.js ===

```
const user = require('./user')()

user.getUser('12345')
  .then(user => {
    console.log(user.xxxx)
  })
```

=== user.js ===

```
const redis = require('redis'),
      Promise = require('bluebird')

function getUser(id) {
  return redis.getAsync(id)
    .then(user => JSON.parse(user))
}

module.exports = () => {
  Promise.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype)
  Promise.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const client = redis.createClient(REDIS_SERVER)
    client.on('connect', onConnect)
    client.on('error', err => {
      throw err
    })

    function onConnect() {
      return resolve({
        getUser
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something to do with TCP fin timeouts(Default 60sec in Linux). Probably you are not reusing connections but opening a new one every time, that is perfectly fine. But If you are doing this so fast that you are risking using all the available ports. You should use this sysctl parameters to reduce tcp fin timeouts and enable tcp_reuse connection.

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10 #value is in seconds
```

**tcp_tw_reuse**
TCP reuse allows Linux kernel to reclaim a connection slot from a connection in TIME_WAIT state and reallocate it to a new connection. Reusing the sockets can be very effective in reducing server load.

**tcp_fin_timeout**
Determines the time that must elapse before TCP/IP can release a closed connection and reuse its resources. During this TIME_WAIT state, reopening the connection to the client costs less than establishing a new connection

Reference: http://www.speedguide.net/articles/linux-broadband-tweaks-121